# (VBA 2010) SaveAs Filename

Tags: vba, excel

I need help to figure out how to get vba to create and save a file in a folder on my desktop after three cells have been filled in by a scanner. Imagine a grocery store scanner, it scans a product. Three pieces of information are  pulled from the bar-code and then placed in three separate cells say A1 B1 C1, how do I get VBA to see this information copy it and paste it into the saved file? this is what i have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Range("A1").Value = "" And Not Range("B1").Value = "" And Not Range("C1").Value = "" Then

        Dim workbookName As String
        workbookName = "DiePunch.csv"
        ActiveCell.Range("A1:C1").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = Fa
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="u:\CSV\Diepunch.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWindow.Close (SaveChange = False)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and those looking to learn) with their code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question][1]. You might also want to [take the tour][2] and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Range("A1").Value = "" And Not Range("B1").Value = "" And Not Range("C1").Value = "" Then

    Dim workbookName As String
    workbookName = "whatever.xls"

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\" & workbookName

End If

End Sub
```

You need to decide how you want to name your file. If you just choose the `workbookName` to be anything, then the files are saved with an increment in the file name, like

```
workbookName(1).xls
workbookName(2).xls
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

I could be more helpful if you could post your code.

Use the cells(row,column) to get the values in the cells.  Creating a file in VBA, I recall is done with the Freefile and Open, Print#, Close syntax.

(This is almost usable code, but not 100%)

```
Dim intHandle as Integer
intHandle = FreeFile()
Open "Filename.txt" for output as intHandle
Print #intHandle, Excel.Cells(Row,Column).Value
Close intHandle
```